# Flash AS2 - Webpage crashes when using LoadVars()

Tags: php, flash, actionscript-2, loadvars

As the title says I am loading a flash in my webpage and when I call **LoadVars()** it crashes the web page.
Here is my code:

**Flash**

```
lv = new LoadVars();   
lv.onLoad = onLoadCallBack;  
lv.load("php/flash_getitems.php");

function onLoadCallBack(succes){
    if(succes){
        t = lv[this.totalItems];
        for(i = 1; i<= t; i++){
            key = this.itemName + "" + i;
            itemList.addItemAt(i, key);
        }
    }

}
stop();
```

**php**

```
INCLUDE 'connector.php';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM shop");
$totalrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
echo "&totalItems=$totalrows";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $id = $row['id'];
        $item = $row['item'];
        $desc = $row['description'];
        $price = $row['price']; 
        echo "&itemName$id=$item";
        echo "&price$id=$price";
        echo "&desc$id=$desc";
    }
```

This will return values like this
**&itemName1=First Item&price1=100&desc1=description**
and so on so forth with the higher id's

Comment: Have you tried it with `include` in lower case?  What happens if you open the PHP in your browser directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like your parsing function has a couple of syntax errors.

See if this works any better:

```
function onLoadCallBack(success){
    if(success){
        for(var i:Number = 1; i<= lv.totalItems; i++)
            itemList.addItemAt(i, lv["itemName"+i]);
    }
}
```

`lv["itemName"+i]` will evaluate to `lv.itemName1`, etc.  You tried to access undefined variables, which causes a null reference error.